# Font awesome icons not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a font awesome icon in front of my Delete & Settings link button but its not working. Can someone please tell me what is missing?

Html Code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings
        </a>           
    </p>
  </div>
```

Added these css:

1) bootstrap.min.css
2) font-awesome.min.css

Also, please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shansubra/py7vA/6/) here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a bug in `3.2.1` for site URLs, fixed in `4.0.3`.  Replace the link external link with http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css

(In HTML, it would be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">`)

**[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py7vA/7/)**

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem, there are too many people out there with BROKEN code examples. Please any developers who decide to publish examples, either keep them up to date or remove them because many people who are looking for information are getting these bad or outdated examples and they do not work. This goes double for anyone publishing info that relies on code referenced, in order to work. You wouldn't release a program linking all icons to some random icons residing on a webpage and expect them to always be present, this is the same thing. If its linked, keep up on it or take it down!

Answer (score 6):

**Try with this..**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete
        </a>
        <br>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings
        </a>           
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Just use the following link**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as yours and I followed the solution from *Wobuffet* but it was not working.

I added `title =""` to the element and it fixed my issue:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I haven't added the fonts to the project. I found an error in developer console and added below fonts to the location where Font Awesome(font-awesome.min.css) is looking for.

[image: Fonts]

Answer (score -1):

link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous"
This link is really worked for me .

Comment: This answer looks the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/64234779/8517948, if you upvote that one instead if it solved your problem it will help more future readers.